# Compojure with Datomic won't compile

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm setting up a compojure app, and I want to have datomic as my database - but as soon as I add the `client-pro` dependency, my app won't run.

Here's what I did:

1. Registered for an account
2. Downloaded `datomic-pro`
3. Created a `transactor.properties` and updated it with the `license-key` I received on my email
4. Ran `bin/transactor transactor.properties`
5. Opened another tab, and created a database:

```
(require ‘[datomic.api :as d])
(def db-uri “datomic:dev://localhost:4334/hello”)
(d/create-database db-uri)
```

6. Started a peer server on another tab

```
bin/run -m datomic.peer-server -h localhost -p 8998 -a myaccesskey,mysecret -d hello,datomic:dev://localhost:4334/hello
```

7. Added `[com.datomic/client-pro “0.8.28”]` to my dependencies

When running `lein ring server` I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.NonBlockingThread
```

Comment: Probably related to conflicting `ring` dependencies. Check `lein deps :tree` and try to use same versions for Ring dependencies. Might have to add something like `[org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util "9.4.17.v20190418"]` manually.

Answer (score 0):

### A Quick Aside

Not a direct answer, but if you are just looking for a fast start with Datomic, you can clone the Tupelo Datomic repo here:

https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo-datomic

It includes a pre-configured version of Datomic Free.  Just run `lein test` to see it in action.  You can then add your own code.

---

### Regarding Jetty

The answer from Erwin may be all you need.  Another possibility is that you may need to add in transitive dependencies at specific versions, and use `:exclude` on others.  Please also note that in `project.clj` important deps **MUST** be listed at the top of the file, as these deps versions (and their transitive deps versions) **WILL OVERRIDE** any deps versions specified later.

I have lein deps for one project that look like this in `project.clj`:

```
  :exclusions [cheshire
               com.cognitect/transit-clj
               com.cognitect/transit-cljs
               com.cognitect/transit-java
               com.cognitect/transit-js
               com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core
               com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
               com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-cbor
               com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-smile
               joda-time/joda-time
               org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server]

  :dependencies [
                 ; fundamental items must come first to override later transitive dependencies
                 [cheshire "5.8.1"]
                 [com.cognitect/transit-clj "0.8.313"]
                 [com.cognitect/transit-cljs "0.8.256"]
                 [com.cognitect/transit-java "0.8.337"]
                 [com.cognitect/transit-js "0.8.861"]
                 [com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core "2.9.9"]
                 [com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind "2.9.9"]
                 [com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-cbor "2.9.9"]
                 [com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-smile "2.9.9"]
                 [joda-time/joda-time "2.10.3"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
                 [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server "9.4.19.v20190610"]
```

then a list of 2nd-tier deps:

```
                 ; high-priority libs, ensure these versions override any transitive dependency versions
                 [binaryage/devtools "0.9.10"]
                 [binaryage/oops "0.7.0"]
                 [com.andrewmcveigh/cljs-time "0.5.2"]
                 [com.cemerick/url "0.1.1"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.4.500" :exclusions [org.clojure/tools.reader]]
                 [org.clojure/core.match "0.3.0"]
                 [org.clojure/test.check "0.9.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.4.2"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.logging "0.5.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.13"] ; #todo #awt upgrade => [nrepl "0.3.1"] from https://github.com/nrepl/nrepl
                 [prismatic/schema "1.1.11"]
                 [tupelo "0.9.144"]
                 [venantius/accountant "0.2.4"]
```

then 3nd-tier deps:

```
                 ; "normal" dependency libs, whose transitive dependencies can be overridden by previous libs
                 [ch.qos.logback/logback-classic "1.2.3"]
                 [clj-http "3.10.0"]
                 [clj-time "0.15.1"] ; #todo switch to java.time & tupelo.java-time
                 [cljsjs/cytoscape "3.1.4-0"]
                 [com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk "1.11.602" :exclusions [joda-time]]
                 [com.taoensso/carmine "2.19.1"]
                 [compojure "1.6.1"]
                 [cprop "0.1.14"]
                 [expound "0.7.2"]
                 [funcool/struct "1.4.0"]
                 [io.janusplatform/janus-environment-config "1.8.7-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [io.janusplatform/janus-logging-java "1.0.11-SNAPSHOT" :exclusions [com.google.guava/guava]]
                 [io.janusplatform/janus-resource-connector "4.3.0-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [jayq "2.5.5"]
                 [luminus-jetty "0.1.7" ]
                 [luminus-nrepl "0.1.6"]
                 [luminus/ring-ttl-session "0.3.3"]
                 [markdown-clj "1.10.0"]
                 [metosin/muuntaja "0.2.1"]
                 [metosin/ring-http-response "0.9.1"]
                 [metosin/spec-tools "0.10.0"]
                 [metosin/scjsv "0.5.0"]
                 [metrics-clojure-ring "2.10.0"]
                 [mount "0.1.16"]
                 [org.webjars/bootstrap "4.3.1"]
                 [org.webjars/font-awesome "5.9.0"]
                 [overtone/at-at "1.2.0"]
                 [ring-webjars "0.2.0"]
                 [ring/ring-codec "1.1.2"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.7.1"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.3.2"]
                 [ring/ring-json "0.4.0"]
                 [throttler "1.0.0"]
```

and some misc deps:

```
                 [amazonica "0.3.145" :exclusions [com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk
                                                   com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core
                                                   com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-cbor
                                                   org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient]]    ; #todo do we really need all these exclusions???

                 [cljs-ajax "0.8.0" :exclusions [cheshire
                                                 com.cognitect/transit-clj
                                                 com.cognitect/transit-java
                                                 org.apache.httpcomponents/httpasyncclient
                                                 org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore
                                                 org.msgpack/msgpack]]    ; #todo do we really need all these exclusions???

                 [org.springframework/spring-webmvc "5.1.8.RELEASE" :exclusions [org.springframework/spring-jcl
                                                                                 org.springframework/spring-aop]]
                 ]
```

You can also see I had to exclude Jetty to prevent a transitive dependency from pulling in the wrong version, then specifically add in the version I wanted.